# Neo4j's MERGE command on big datasets

Tags: merge, neo4j, bigdata, nodes, graph-databases

Currently, I am working on a project of implementing a Neo4j (V2.2.0) database in the field of web-analytics. After loading some samples, I'm trying to load a big data set (>1GB, >4M lines). The problem I am facing, is that the usage of the MERGE command takes exponentially more time as the data size grows. Online sources are ambiguous on what the best way is to load big sets of data when not every line has to be loaded as a node, and I would like some clarity on the subject. To emphasize, in this situation I am just loading the nodes; relations are the next step.

Basically there are three methods

i) Set a uniqueness constraint for a property, and create all nodes. This method was used mainly before the MERGE command was introduced.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

followed by

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 250
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\path\\file.tsv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR'\t'
CREATE (:Book{isbn=row.isbn, title=row.title, etc})
```

In my experience, this will return a error if a duplicate is found, which stops the query.

ii) Merging the nodes with all their properties.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 250
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\path\\file.tsv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR'\t'
MERGE (:Book{isbn=row.isbn, title=row.title, etc})
```

I have tried loading my set in this manner, but after letting the process run for over 36 hours and coming to a grinding halt, I figured there should be a better alternative, as ~200K of my eventual ~750K nodes were loaded.

iii) Merging nodes based on one property, and setting the rest after that.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 250
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\path\\file.tsv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR'\t'
MERGE (b:Book{isbn=row.isbn})
ON CREATE SET b.title = row.title
ON CREATE SET b.author = row.author
etc
```

I am running a test now (~20K nodes) to see if switching from method ii to iii will improve execution time, as a smaller sample gave conflicting results. Are there methods which I am overseeing and could improve execution time? If I am not mistaken, the batch inserter only works for the CREATE command, and not the MERGE command.

I have permitted Neo4j to use 4GB of RAM, and judging from my task manager this is enough (uses just over 3GB).

Comment: AFAIK, method iii) will make use of the index to find the node, while method ii) will not (because of matching multiple properties). Have you also tried increasing the number of ops in each transaction to 1000 for example?

Comment: I lowered it initially, because I was thinking Neo4j wasn't handling the loading well when I had set it at 1000. After finding the real problem with that setup, I haven't raised it back to 1000, so I'll do that again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method iii) should be the fastest solution since you `MERGE` against a single property. Do you create the uniqueness constraint before you do the `MERGE`? Without an index (constraint or normal index), the process will take a long time with a growing number of nodes.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Followed by:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 20000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:\\path\\file.tsv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR'\t'
MERGE (b:Book{isbn=row.isbn})
ON CREATE SET b.title = row.title
ON CREATE SET b.author = row.author
```

This should work, you can increase the `PERIODIC COMMIT`.

I can add a few hundred thousand nodes within minutes this way.

Comment: Awesome! This combination improves the execution time greatly (16 seconds vs 30 min). Only problem is that is doesn't appear to load all the data from the file. It loads 20000 nodes, where method ii) loaded 20506. Any idea how this is caused? EDIT: Combining the constraint with method ii returns errors regarding the unique constraint so that's not an option

Comment: If you create the uniqueness constraint on `isbn`, both methods should create the same number of nodes (even though ii) merges on multiple properties). Try to reduce to `PERIODIC COMMIT 1000` for testing. How many unique `isbn` do you have in the test data set?

Comment: Apparently, the 20000 is correct, as adding a dummy line to the file does increase the amount of nodes to 20001. The 20506 then must be caused by inconsistency in the data

Comment: I haven't extracted the raw data myself. It should be 20000, but because of more inconsistencies in the data i had received, I was doubting this was correct.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The >1GB file is now loaded in roughly half an hour, much better then my first attempts

Answer (score 0):

In general, make sure you have indexes in place.  Merge a node first on the basis of the properties that are indexed (to exploit fast lookup) and then modify that node's properties as needed with `SET`.

Beyond that, both of your approaches are going through the transaction layer.  If you need to jam a lot of data into the DB really quickly, you probably don't want to use transactions to do that, because they're giving you functionality you might not need, and they require overhead that's slowing you down.   So a larger solution would be to not insert data with `LOAD CSV` but go another route entirely.

If you're using the 2.2 series of neo4j, you can go for the [batch inserter via java](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert.html), or the [neo4j-import tool](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets) sadly not available prior to 2.2.  What they both have in common is that they don't use transactions.

Finally, either way you go you should read [Michael Hunger's article on importing data into neo4j](http://jexp.de/blog/2013/05/on-importing-data-in-neo4j-blog-series/) as it provides a good conceptual discussion of what's happening, and why you need to skip transactions if you're going to load big huge piles of data into neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the indices and transaction layer. I'll have a look into the tools somewhere next week, as further improvement on execution times is more then welcome. First got to finish up a proof of concept in a timely fashion, so I prefer to work with the tools I'm familiar with so far.